# I can not sent short messages by TCP protocol

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I have a trouble to tune TCP client-server communication.

My current project has a client, running on PC (C#) and a server,
running on embedded Linux 4.1.22-ltsi.
Them use UDP communication to exchanging data.

The client and server work in blocking mode and
send short messages one to 2nd
(16, 60, 200 bytes etc.) that include either command or set of parameters.

The messages do note include any header with message length because
UDP is message oriented protocol. Its `recvfrom()` API returns number of received bytes.

For my server's program structure is important to get and process entire alone message.

The problem is raised when I try to implement TCP communication type instead of UDP.

The server's receive buffer (`recv()` TCP API) is 2048 bytes:

```
#define UDP_RX_BUF_SIZE 2048
numbytes = recv(fd_connect, rx_buffer, UDP_RX_BUF_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL/*BLOCKING_MODE*/);
```

So, the `recv()` API returns from waiting when `rx_buffer` is full, i.e after it receives
2048 bytes.  It breaks all program approach. In other words, when client send 16 bytes command
to server and waits an answer from it, server's `recv()` keeps the message
"in stomach", until it will receive 2048 bytes.

I tried to fix it as below, without success:

1. On client side (C#) I set the socket parameter `theSocket.NoDelay`.
   When I checked this on the sniffer I saw that client sends messages "as I want",
   with requested length.
2. On server side I set TCP_NODELAY socket option to 1

```
int optval= 1;
setsockopt(fd,IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &optval, sizeof(optval);
```

3. On server side (Linux) I checked socket options `SO_SNDLOWAT/SO_RCVLOWAT` and they are 1 byte each one.

Please see the attached sniffer's log picture. 10.0.0.10 is a client. 10.0.0.106 is a server. It is seen, that client activates PSH flag (push), informing the server side to move the incoming data to application immediately and do not fill a buffer.

Additional question: what is SSH encrypted packets that runs between the sides. I suppose that it is my Eclipse debugger on PC (running server application through the same Ethernet connection) sends them. Am I right?

So, my problem is how to cause `recv() API to return each short message (16, 60, 200 bytes etc.) instead of accumulating them until receiving buffer fills.

[image]

Comment: I'm kind of puzzled. You seem to understand that the only reason you don't need a header with the message length is that UDP is a message oriented protocol. Since TCP is not, why do you think you still don't need a header with the message length?

Comment: 'Server's `recv()` keeps the message "in stomach", until it will receive 2048 bytes'. This is only because you specified `MSG_WAITALL`, which, contrary to your comment, is not 'blocking mode', it tells TCP to try to fill the entire buffer. Solution: don't use it.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne, "The client and server work in blocking mode" - it is the quote of my post. If I set the option to MSG_DONTWAIT, the recv() will return immediately, that is not my approach.

Comment: @Yakov 1. The claim that `MSG_WAITALL` represents blocking mode is right there in a comment in your code. 2. There is nothing in my comment about using `MSG_DONTWAIT`. You made that up. Don't use that either. Try 0.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is connection oriented and it also maintains the order in which packets are sent and received.

Having said that, in TCP client, you will receive the stream of bytes and not the individual udp message as in UDP. So you will need to send the packet length and marker as the initial bytes.

So client can first find the packet length and then read data till packet length is reached and then expect new packet length.

You can also check for library like netty, zmq to do this extra work